# Confusion while populating combobox

Tags: c#

I have a table named `Departmants`, which consist of 4 Fields: `DepId`, `DepName`, `DoctorId`, `PatientId`.

I am attempting to populate a combobox control with department names, using the following code:

```
 public void ListDeps(ComboBox comboBox1)
 {
     DepartmantClass d;  //I have created this class with the same fields in the Departmants table
     try
     {
         con = Baglanti.Baglan();
         cmdStr = "Select * from Departmants";
         cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con);
         if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) { con.Open();}
         SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
         if (reader.HasRows)
         {
             d = new Bolumler();
             while (reader.Read())
             {
                d.DepName = reader["DepName"].ToString();
                d.DoctorId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["DoctorId"].ToString());
                d.DepId= Convert.ToInt32(reader["DepId"].ToString());
                comboBox1.Items.Add(d);
             }
         }
         reader.Close();
     }
 }

 private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     DepartmantClass d= new DepartmantClass ();              
     d.ListDeps(cmbDepNames);
 }
```

Everything is ok. The problem is (I think) I can't pass the values to the `combobox` properly.
Because when I execute the following line in the `comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler - I have noticed that all the values are the same.

```
MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Comment: Though not related to the question, you should consider changing `select *` due to the reasons given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap these

```
 d = new Bolumler();
   while (reader.Read())
  {
 ...
```

to

```
while (reader.Read())
      {
     d = new Bolumler();
...
```

So you create a new instance of Bolumler on each iteration.